# how to Hide a div when css is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div which is hidden initially and will be visible later depending on some click events results.

I have wrote this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%=disable.ClientID %>').hide();
});


 <div id="disable" runat="server">The following question is disabled</div>
```

But when i disable CSS it appears, when i don't disable css it gets invisible. how do i make this invisible even when css is disabled and visible later again

Comment: Why would you disable css?

Comment: Since you will have Javascript still running, you could just delete the element and create it again. But I never hear about people disabling CSS.

Comment: I'd be more worried about JS being disabled and not the CSS...

Comment: This could be relevant for some screen reader's for blind people.

Comment: and since you're using asp.net and you have the `runat=server` on the div, the div is available in the code behind as `disable.visible=TRUE|FALSE`

Comment: why are you disabling CSS? Your options are pretty straight forward when it comes to showing/hiding DOM elements. CSS and/or Javascript.

Comment: i still need to be able to hide it from client side and server side both. This is a requirement for blind users

Comment: you might want to check out this article:  http://speckyboy.com/2013/02/04/myths-about-how-blind-people-use-the-internet/. Here is a quote: "For example did you know that any page elements with the CSS property display:none won’t be read by a screenreader?"

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make something *invisible* without CSS. But you can remove it:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%=disable.ClientID %>').remove();
});
```

You would then need to readd all the mark up again should you wish to show it again.

### Edit

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var item = $('#<%=disable.ClientID %>');
        $(document).data('myElement', item.clone());
        item.remove();
});
```

then you could re-add it

```
 $(document).append($(document).data('myElement'));
```

Comment: There is something like a `clone` command right? clone it before removing it. That way you can readd it easy again? I'm sorry if im speaking nonsense now, i thought i read that somewhere

Comment: Dude, your pun is unbearable

Comment: Just deleted my answer in favor of this one. This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to write server code for this, then you could do this in the code-behind.

```
//  c#
if(some condition...)
{
    disable.Visible = false;
}
```

This will remove the div from the HTML output of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get you when talking about enabling and disabling `css`, but you can always manage the DOM elements via DOM manipulation. As you tagged `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* please try top avoid mix server side variables and javascript code */
    $('#myTargetDiv').hide();

    $('#myToggleButton').on('click',function(){
        /* select the elements you want to hide / show with the click on this element */
        var $elements = $('#myTargetDiv');
        $elements.toggle();
    });
});
```